# Webpack outputs wrong image path

Tags: css, laravel, webpack

I'm using Webpack/Laravel Mix. On my original Sass file, a certain path looks like this:

```
.is-gplay {
  background-image: url(../images/bcg/gplay.png);
}
```

Mix and webpack will then find the image and copy it to **public/images**. It will also rewrite the path within the new css file to

```
.is-gplay {
  background-image: url(/images/gplay.png?d1b4cc17fbb3149178c9a1a6a47e33f);
}
```

Great. Except it copied the picture to **public/images** and wrote a path to **public/css/images**, so now the browser won't find it unless I edit my compiled css and add ../ in front of the image path so it sees the images folder is outside the css folder by default.

What am I missing here? Why does it create an images folder outside the css folder and then writes a path to css/images?

Sorry if this is something simple I'm not realizing right now. It's my first time working with webpack.

Comment: I think I ran into a similar situation when I first used webpack… Could you provide us with you `webpack.config.js` file?

Comment: @Julio Kirk as chriskirknielsen stated, without example, it is hard to tell. But another question is, can you access your image via url /images/... If not, then you probably have a problem with your webserver configuration.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen as Bart pointed out, I had a problem with my webserver configuration and webpack was fine. Actually I've been using php's server for now and decided not to use Apache during development. Thanks a lot both of you for taking the time to answer :)